# Question on credible intervals for the parameter of an exponential distribution with Gamma prior

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

Suppose we have a random sample $X_1, ..., X_n$ where $X \sim$ Expo$(\theta)$ (here $\theta$ is the rate). We're studying the Bayes estimator of $\theta$ and its properties. For a Gamma$(\alpha, \beta)$ ($\beta$ as scale) prior, I found the posterior distribution to be $$\text{Gamma}(\alpha + n, \left( \sum X_i + 1 / \beta \right)^{-1})$$ and consequently the Bayes estimator as $$T^{B}(X_1, ..., X_n) = \frac{\alpha + n}{\sum X_i + 1 / \beta}. $$

Now I'm tasked to find a credible region for $\theta$, but I'm quite confused on how to find this. Initially I thought this could just be the quantiles of our posterior distribution, but looking a bit around online, this doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: Always, when dealing with exponential and gamma distributions, you need to say which parameterization you are using. For exponential, is  $\theta$ the mean or the rate? Fpr gamma, is $\beta$ scale or rate. // I think you're right about using quantiles of the posterior distribution. If you're using R for that, then R default uses rate parameter for both distributions. Your question might be clearer if you gave a specific numerical example with numerical values of $\alpha, \beta, \theta,$ and total of observations. Also, if you showed your answer corresponding to those numerical values.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the comment! Indeed, I will add what the parameters of the distributions mean. I'm not doing any numerical calculations here, I was just confused on what exactly the credible region is and how to find it. So I chose this exercises as an example to get more insight. I guess I'm just confused because in some cases people seem to 'transform' the posterior distribution a bit to get a more 'cleaner' credible interval. For example I know that $\sum X_i \sim$ Gamma$(n, 1/ \theta)$ in this case, but I've also seen people using $2 \theta \sum X_i \sim \chi^2(n)$ online to get

Comment: a better result.

Comment: Not better. Equivalent, if conversion is correct. Just allows use of printed chi-squared tables to avoid software for those still in 20th century. Retracted vote to close, pending edit to clarify parameters.

Comment: @BruceET I meant 'better' in the sense of 'more clean'. My class is not dealing with any numerics, so I'm just trying to understand the concept of the credible intervals. I will not  be dealing with any tables.